# How can I update and new table based on 3 columns from an old table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

1. `new_product` with columns:

   ```
   id_product, 
   id_category, 
   id_combination, 
   id_feature, 
   whole_sale_price, 
   retail_price,
   ```
2. `old_product` with columns:

   ```
   id_product, 
   id_category, 
   id_combination, 
   id_feature, 
   whole_sale_price, 
   retail_price,
   ```

How can I update the data from the columns `whole_sale_price` and `retail_price` on `new_product` using the value from the columns `whole_sale_price` and `retail_price` from `old_product` using as key `id_category`, `id_combination` and `id_feature`?

Comment: you mean `UPDATE table a SET valA=tableB.valueB, valC=tableD.valueD WHERE tableB.key='something' AND tableD.key='something else'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a general way you could write it as follows:

```
UPDATE
  table1 AS target,
  (SELECT column1, column2 FROM table2) AS source
SET
  target.column3 = source.column1
WHERE
  target.column4 = source.column2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update `whole_sale_price` and `retail_price`, you can use this query:

```
UPDATE new_product as newP
JOIN old_product as oldP
ON newP.id_category = oldP.id_category AND
   newP.id_combination = oldP.id_combination AND
   newP.id_feature = oldP.id_feature
SET newP.whole_sale_price = oldP.whole_sale_price,
newP.retail_price = oldP.retail_price
```